# delay in lyrics shown when concat video with lyrics with an intro video using ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have a video with lyrics I add the lyrics used ffmpeg too. I have the lyrics in lrc formate and i change it to ass lyrics formate then I start to add it to my video using this command

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -vf "ass=out.ass,fade=in:0:30" -y amr.mp4
```

I use fade=in:0:30 to make fade in the start of the video so when I start merge intro video my original video not start at once but to have some fade in, in the start to have a good view.
then I start to add the intro video using a text file which has this

```
file intro.mp4
file amr.mp4
```

then I merge them using this command

```
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i out.txt -c copy -y final.mp4
```

i got these message

```
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 03eadb80] Auto-inserting h264_mp4toannexb bitstream filter
[mp4 @ 06419580] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 310272,     current: 285626; changing to 310273. This may result in incorrect timestamps in   the output file.
```

repeated many times.
 when i watch the final video the lyrics have some delay from the sound the problem appeared when I merge the intro video but without it the lyrics have no problem so what I made wrong make the lyrics shown in this way and not in the right timing as it should have no problems as I merge only the intro video and after add the lyrics to the original one 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Sounds like the intro's audio and main audio don't have same properties or the intro audio's duration is not same as intro video stream.

Comment: Yes the intro video is 7 seconds and the main video is 3 minute if so how can I make them have the same properties as use this command to make the 2 videos have the same frame and resultion so they can be concate without a problem
 ffmpeg -y -i source.mp4 -r 25 -s 160x90 -c:v libx264 -b:v 3M -strict -2 -movflags faststart destination.mp4